# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

I have an app in which I need to parse configuration file and when run this program on server it gives the following trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
    at com.messagedna.server.startup.StartupServlet.init(StartupServlet.java:19)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5320)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 48 more
```

apache commons **exists** in my classpath. it is. and nevertheless I have such a problem.

in firebug in firefox I see the following trace in tomcat log:

```
<b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Actually I'm not shure this two exceptions have the same reasons.
I'll be very grateful if somebody can advise me the way of solution of such problems

**UPD:** here is my pom.xml file:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>DLP</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
  <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>DLPServer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>DLPServer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
          <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
          <version>1.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
          <version>0.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
          <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>net.freeutils.jtnef</groupId>
          <artifactId>tnef</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.messagedna-archive.mimeparser</groupId>
          <artifactId>MimeParser</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
          <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.10</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.2</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>compile</goal>
                              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                              <goal>test</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                      <runTarget>Main.html</runTarget>
                      <style>OBFUSCATED</style>
                      <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024m -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                      <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.1.1</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
                      <warSourceExcludes>.gwt-tmp/**</warSourceExcludes>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in idea(I use intellij Idea) properties. they were broken for some reason. I didn't found what exectly was wrong(something with running config) and deleted all idea files, created a new project and imported my modules into this project, where my program began working.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the lib is contained in the lib folder of your app, it might be possible that you left it via packaging via ant or maven. the next probable reason might be that you jar is corrupted. try to decompile and check(though this is very rare).

Allways do remeber classNotFound exception simply means that your program is unable to find concern class for whatsoever reason. add it to your lib/classpath. There is no other reason possible.

Comment: It is evident from the output, but the reason of this, when all libraries are in the classpath, is not evident

Comment: what do you mean by class path.. I have seen cases where people add liberaries to classpath of eclipse, while prefer packaging by maven or ant. Is your case same?? .

Comment: I've added apache-commons-configuration and commons-lang dependences to the pom file of my app

Comment: hmm this cannot be solved by the traces you provided. Atleast I cant figure the exact problem. do one thing, post your pom file. remove all  code from you app and just write a simple program to read and display configurations on index page. then post your that little code as well. by this we can replicate issue to help.

Comment: I've posted my pom file. And as for the simple app: I can't imagine app which use all this libraries simplier than mine

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Commons Lang on your path also? If not, Eclipse will fail to resolve the ConfigurationException class, and you'll get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I run the app on another instance of Glassfish runtime environment 3.1.2 and it works!! I was using 3.1.2.2

It could be the corrupted glassfish server instance or a bug in the glassfish server 3.1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh really, there is a problem with JetBrains IDE. Invalidate cache and restart helps me.